# setting ConverterParameter in style

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type propgrid:PropertyGridDataAccessorItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="DataAccessorType" Value="Category">
                   <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding DisplayName, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, ConverterParameter=???, Converter={local:ExpandedCategoryConverter}}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to send as ConverterParameter a property from my ViewModel. I would like to have something like ConverterParameter= "{Binding MyValue}", but it is imposible. I tryed Multibinding like this :

```
<Trigger Property="DataAccessorType" Value="Category">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded">   
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{local:ExpandedCategoryConverter}">
                <Binding Path="DisplayName"/>
                <Binding Path="MyProperty"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

but my property is always null.

Anybody knows how to deal with this problem?

Thnx in advance

Comment: Are there any binding error messages in the VS Output window? At least in the single binding you are setting `RelativeSource`, but you don't do that in the MultiBinding.

Comment: In my converter class in debug mode I get DisplayName fine, but ExpandCategory is - unset({DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}).
Any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: What is ExpandCategory? Can't find that in your question. And are there binding error messages or not? Please look at the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run your application.

Comment: It's name of my property in viewModel. Here in code it's the same as MyProperty

Comment: What about binding error messages?

Comment: in output window there are no binding errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` for `MyProperty` (or `ExpandCategory`) because the binding does not produce a value. The MSDN documentation of the `values` parameter of the [IMultiValueConverter.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convert.aspx) method says:

> *values*
>
> > The array of values that the source bindings in the MultiBinding
> >     produces. The value **UnsetValue** indicates that the source binding has
> >     no value to provide for conversion.

You have to make sure that `<Binding Path="MyProperty"/>` works. I guess you haven't properly set the source of the binding.

Comment: Thnx for you help, I found it with such line : RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"